# One object is displayed multiple times when its number of likes are updated in angular firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm building a like/dislike system for posts on my website. Every time the user clicks on the like button, the number of likes gets updated in the database. The object stored in the database has a URL of the image, a category and the number of likes as its keys.

Following is my code to update: `likedButton(img)` is a function which is called when the user clicks the like button.

```
likedButton(img) {
  var url = img.src;
  var x = this.db
    .list('/userPosts', ref => ref.orderByChild('url').equalTo(url));

  x.snapshotChanges().first()
    .subscribe((datas) => {
      var keys = datas[0]['key'];
      var obj = x.valueChanges().first().subscribe((z) => {
        var n: number = z[0]['likes'];
        firebase.database().ref('/userPosts/' + keys).update({
          'likes': n + 1
        });
      });
    });
}
```

If I press the like button, one post is displayed multiple times in Angular 6.

Below is my display function:

```
constructor(
  public db: AngularFireDatabase, 
  private router: Router, 
  public authService: AuthService
) {

  db.list('/userPosts').valueChanges().subscribe(images => {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this.image, images);
    this.image.reverse();
  });

  this.authService.af.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user != null) {
      this.logged = true;
      this.userName = user.displayName;
    }
  });
}
```

This is the template

```
<ul class="images">
    <li *ngFor="let image of image | imagefilter : x "> 
        <img #img src="{{image.url}}" [ngStyle]="{'width':'26%','height':'26%'}" [className]="'img-thumbnail'">
        <button (click)="likedButton(img)" class="btn btn-primary">Like &nbsp;{{image.likes}}</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You may want to iterate your array, and check if your item is already in there (by checking IDs or something) before pushing it in

Comment: @user184994 duplicate posts are removed, but an additional like button is created. :(

Comment: Can you add the HTML template responsible for displaying the like button please?

Comment: <ul class="images">
      <li *ngFor = "let image of image | imagefilter : x ">
    <img #img src="{{image.url}}" [ngStyle] = "{'width':'26%','height':'26%'}" [className]  ="'img-thumbnail'">
<button (click) = "likedButton(img)" class="btn btn-primary">Like &nbsp;{{image.likes}}</button>
      </li>
  </ul>

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that a like button shouldn't be created as long as you're not pushing a duplicate into that array?